# OracleSQL: Assigning employees to groups with date values, querying current assignments by date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database which consists of employees (one table) which can be assigned to groups (another table). Bother are joined together with another table, employee-to-group, which lists the group id, the employee id and the start date of the assignment.

An employee always has to be assigned to a group, but the assignments can change daily. One employee could be working in group A for day, then change into group B and work in group C only a week later.

My task is to find out which employees are assigned to a certain group given by its name at any given date. So the input should be: group name, date and I want the output to be the data of all the employees which are part of that group at the given moment in time.

Here's an SQL fiddle with some test data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d0bb

I recreated the database with mysql-statements because I couldn't figure out the oracle statements, I'm sorry.

As you can see from the test data, some employees may never change groups, while others change frequently. THere are also employees which are planned to change assignments in the future. The query has to account for that.

Because the application is a legacy one, the values (especially in the date field) are questionable. They are given as "days since the 1st of january, 1990", so the entry "9131" means "1st of january, 2015". 9468 would be today (2015-12-04) and 9496 would be 2016-01-01).

What I already have is code to find out the "date value" for any given date in what I call the "legacy format" of the application I'm working with (here I've just used CURRENT_DATE):

```
SELECT FLOOR(CURRENT_DATE - TO_DATE('1990-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS diffdate
```

For finding out which group a certain employee is assigned to, I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM history h 
WHERE emp_nr = 1 AND valid_from <= 9131
ORDER BY valid_from DESC 
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

which *should* return me the group which an employee is assigned to on the 1st of january 2015.

What I do need help with is creating a statement that joins all tables does the same for a whole group instead of only one employee (as there are thousands of employees in the database and I only want the data of at most 10 groups).

I'm thankful for any kind of pointers in the right direction.

Comment: As to " I only want the data of at most 10 groups": How would you decide which groups? Just by `where group.nr in (10,20,30,...)` or by some algorithm you want applied?

Comment: Yes, I will just use a WHERE clause to filter out the groups I need to get the data from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use row_number to rank your history and get the latest group, just as you did with your FETCH FIRST query:

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    h.*,
    row_number() over (partition by emp_nr order by valid_from desc) as rn
  from history h 
  where valid_from <= 9131
)
where rn = 1
```

You can then join this result with other tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. Your remark about using row_number helped me solve my problem. I was able to finalize my query now and it is working as intended. I guess my problem was that I don't have a strong background in Oracle SQL, so I didn't know about this function.

Comment: I am glad this works for you. There is nothing Oracle specific in this query however; it's plain standard SQL (apart from the fact that the derived table would need an alias name in standard SQL, whereas Oracle is able to do without). It's worth looking at analytic functions (aka windowing functions) like `row_number`. It is very easy for example to get a running total (with `sum over`), which is troublesome without them. Some DBMS (e.g. MySQL) don't support analytic functions (yet), so rather simple tasks like these can become hard to solve there.

Comment: Most of my SQL knowledge derives from using MySQL, so I guess that's why I didn't know about analytic functions. But hey, thanks for pointing that out, I'll surely look into this topic now :)